# use data from server in angularjs template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to view data received from server in angular template. I receive valid response from server and I just want to put the data into the template.
Here is my controller:

```
'use strict';

(function() {
    angular
        .module('myApp')
        .controller('myController.ctrl', myController);

    myController.$inject = ['$scope', 'websocket.srvc','$http'];

    function myController($scope, websocketSrvc, $http) {
        angular.extend(this, {
            getIncrementalId: getIncrementalId
        });

        function getIncrementalId() {
            $http.get('/backend/screen-sharingId').
            then(function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                $scope.id = response.data;
                return response.data;
            }, function(response) {
                // called asynchronously if an error occurs
                // or server returns response with an error status.
            });

        }

        this.id = (typeof this.id === 'undefined') ? getIncrementalId() : this.id;

    }
})();
```

and my simple template:

```
 <div id = "command"><p class = "bg-info">Command for connecting to the server: </p></br> ID:<span id = "command">{{ vm.id }}</span></div>
```

When I execute the code I dont see anything next to ID:
Should I invoke $rootScope.$apply()?

Thank you!

Comment: what is VM ? 

Is it the right controller ?

Comment: vm is the correct controller for the corresponding template

Comment: myController = screenSharingCtrl?

Comment: correct, my fault
Post updated

Comment: If the template has access to the controller, you should be able to reference values on scope directly. That is, to reference the result that you stored in `$scope.id`, you can simply refer to it as `id`